# "xm save" fails on kernel.org domU with Xen 3.4.1

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen, kernel

I've installed Xen 3.4.1 from source. Some of my paravirt domUs use the official XenLinux kernel (2.6.18) and some use the mainline kernel.org.

When I run "xm save" on the kernel.org guests, the "xm save" command hangs where its run in dom0, and on the domU console I get an error:

```
PM: Device rtc_cmos failed to suspend: error -22
xen suspend: dpm_suspend_start -22
```

I'm using kernel version 2.6.31.4 for the domU, which I've built from source (the XenLinux domUs suspend without a problem).

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the Xen config file for the domU in question:

```
#
# Configuration file for the Xen instance lit, created
# by xen-tools 4.1 on Sat Jul 25 11:01:31 2009.
#

#
#  Kernel + memory size
#
kernel      = '/opt/xen/linux-2.6.31.4/vmlinuz'
memory      = '128'

#
#  Disk device(s).
#
root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'
disk        = [
                 'phy:/dev/vg00/lit-disk,xvda2,w',
                 'phy:/dev/vg00/lit-swap,xvda1,w',
             ]

#
#  Hostname
#
name        = 'lit'

#
#  Networking
#
vif         = [ 'ip=192.168.1.28,mac=00:16:3E:9A:C1:8B' ]

#
#  Behaviour
#
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'

extra='console=hvc0'
```

And here is the .config file to build the domU kernel:

```
#############################################################
#
# Automatically generated make config: don't edit
# Linux kernel version: 2.6.31.4
# Sun Oct 18 20:29:57 2009
#
CONFIG_64BIT=y
# CONFIG_X86_32 is not set
CONFIG_X86_64=y
CONFIG_X86=y
CONFIG_OUTPUT_FORMAT="elf64-x86-64"
CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig"
CONFIG_GENERIC_TIME=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_CMOS_UPDATE=y
CONFIG_CLOCKSOURCE_WATCHDOG=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_CLOCKEVENTS=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_CLOCKEVENTS_BROADCAST=y
CONFIG_LOCKDEP_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_STACKTRACE_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_HAVE_LATENCYTOP_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_FAST_CMPXCHG_LOCAL=y
CONFIG_MMU=y
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_ISA_DMA=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_IOMAP=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_BUG=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_BUG_RELATIVE_POINTERS=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HWEIGHT=y
CONFIG_ARCH_MAY_HAVE_PC_FDC=y
CONFIG_RWSEM_GENERIC_SPINLOCK=y
# CONFIG_RWSEM_XCHGADD_ALGORITHM is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_CPU_IDLE_WAIT=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_CALIBRATE_DELAY=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_TIME_VSYSCALL=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_CPU_RELAX=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_DEFAULT_IDLE=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_CACHE_LINE_SIZE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_SETUP_PER_CPU_AREA=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DYNAMIC_PER_CPU_AREA=y
CONFIG_HAVE_CPUMASK_OF_CPU_MAP=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HIBERNATION_POSSIBLE=y
CONFIG_ARCH_SUSPEND_POSSIBLE=y
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA32=y
CONFIG_ARCH_POPULATES_NODE_MAP=y
CONFIG_AUDIT_ARCH=y
CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_OPTIMIZED_INLINING=y
CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS_NO__DO_IRQ=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_IRQ_PROBE=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_PENDING_IRQ=y
CONFIG_USE_GENERIC_SMP_HELPERS=y
CONFIG_X86_64_SMP=y
CONFIG_X86_HT=y
CONFIG_X86_TRAMPOLINE=y
# CONFIG_KTIME_SCALAR is not set
CONFIG_DEFCONFIG_LIST="/lib/modules/$UNAME_RELEASE/.config"
CONFIG_CONSTRUCTORS=y

#
# General setup
#
CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL=y
CONFIG_LOCK_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_INIT_ENV_ARG_LIMIT=32
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-xen-domU-64"
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_GZIP=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_BZIP2=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZMA=y
CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP=y
# CONFIG_KERNEL_BZIP2 is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZMA is not set
CONFIG_SWAP=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE=y
CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT=y
CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT_V3=y
CONFIG_TASKSTATS=y
CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT=y
CONFIG_TASK_XACCT=y
CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING=y
CONFIG_AUDIT=y
CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL=y
CONFIG_AUDIT_TREE=y

#
# RCU Subsystem
#
CONFIG_CLASSIC_RCU=y
# CONFIG_TREE_RCU is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU is not set
# CONFIG_TREE_RCU_TRACE is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU_TRACE is not set
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT=15
CONFIG_HAVE_UNSTABLE_SCHED_CLOCK=y
# CONFIG_GROUP_SCHED is not set
# CONFIG_CGROUPS is not set
# CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2 is not set
# CONFIG_RELAY is not set
# CONFIG_NAMESPACES is not set
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=""
CONFIG_RD_GZIP=y
# CONFIG_RD_BZIP2 is not set
# CONFIG_RD_LZMA is not set
CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE=y
CONFIG_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_ANON_INODES=y
CONFIG_EMBEDDED=y
CONFIG_UID16=y
CONFIG_SYSCTL_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
# CONFIG_KALLSYMS_EXTRA_PASS is not set
CONFIG_HOTPLUG=y
CONFIG_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_BUG=y
CONFIG_ELF_CORE=y
# CONFIG_PCSPKR_PLATFORM is not set
CONFIG_BASE_FULL=y
CONFIG_FUTEX=y
CONFIG_EPOLL=y
CONFIG_SIGNALFD=y
CONFIG_TIMERFD=y
CONFIG_EVENTFD=y
CONFIG_SHMEM=y
CONFIG_AIO=y
CONFIG_HAVE_PERF_COUNTERS=y

#
# Performance Counters
#
# CONFIG_PERF_COUNTERS is not set
CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS=y
# CONFIG_STRIP_ASM_SYMS is not set
# CONFIG_COMPAT_BRK is not set
CONFIG_SLAB=y
# CONFIG_SLUB is not set
# CONFIG_SLOB is not set
# CONFIG_PROFILING is not set
# CONFIG_MARKERS is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_OPROFILE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EFFICIENT_UNALIGNED_ACCESS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_IOREMAP_PROT=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KRETPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_TRACEHOOK=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DMA_ATTRS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DMA_API_DEBUG=y

#
# GCOV-based kernel profiling
#
# CONFIG_SLOW_WORK is not set
# CONFIG_HAVE_GENERIC_DMA_COHERENT is not set
CONFIG_SLABINFO=y
CONFIG_RT_MUTEXES=y
CONFIG_BASE_SMALL=0
# CONFIG_MODULES is not set
CONFIG_STOP_MACHINE=y
CONFIG_BLOCK=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG is not set
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INTEGRITY is not set
CONFIG_BLOCK_COMPAT=y

#
# IO Schedulers
#
CONFIG_IOSCHED_NOOP=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_AS=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_DEADLINE=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ=y
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_AS is not set
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEADLINE is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_CFQ=y
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_NOOP is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_IOSCHED="cfq"
CONFIG_FREEZER=y

#
# Processor type and features
#
CONFIG_TICK_ONESHOT=y
# CONFIG_NO_HZ is not set
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_CLOCKEVENTS_BUILD=y
CONFIG_SMP=y
CONFIG_X86_MPPARSE=y
# CONFIG_X86_EXTENDED_PLATFORM is not set
CONFIG_SCHED_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_PARAVIRT_GUEST=y
CONFIG_XEN=y
CONFIG_XEN_MAX_DOMAIN_MEMORY=4
CONFIG_XEN_SAVE_RESTORE=y
# CONFIG_KVM_CLOCK is not set
# CONFIG_KVM_GUEST is not set
CONFIG_PARAVIRT=y
CONFIG_PARAVIRT_SPINLOCKS=y
CONFIG_PARAVIRT_CLOCK=y
# CONFIG_MEMTEST is not set
# CONFIG_M386 is not set
# CONFIG_M486 is not set
# CONFIG_M586 is not set
# CONFIG_M586TSC is not set
# CONFIG_M586MMX is not set
# CONFIG_M686 is not set
# CONFIG_MPENTIUMII is not set
# CONFIG_MPENTIUMIII is not set
# CONFIG_MPENTIUMM is not set
# CONFIG_MPENTIUM4 is not set
# CONFIG_MK6 is not set
# CONFIG_MK7 is not set
CONFIG_MK8=y
# CONFIG_MCRUSOE is not set
# CONFIG_MEFFICEON is not set
# CONFIG_MWINCHIPC6 is not set
# CONFIG_MWINCHIP3D is not set
# CONFIG_MGEODEGX1 is not set
# CONFIG_MGEODE_LX is not set
# CONFIG_MCYRIXIII is not set
# CONFIG_MVIAC3_2 is not set
# CONFIG_MVIAC7 is not set
# CONFIG_MPSC is not set
# CONFIG_MCORE2 is not set
# CONFIG_GENERIC_CPU is not set
CONFIG_X86_CPU=y
CONFIG_X86_L1_CACHE_BYTES=64
CONFIG_X86_INTERNODE_CACHE_BYTES=64
CONFIG_X86_CMPXCHG=y
CONFIG_X86_L1_CACHE_SHIFT=6
CONFIG_X86_WP_WORKS_OK=y
CONFIG_X86_INTEL_USERCOPY=y
CONFIG_X86_USE_PPRO_CHECKSUM=y
CONFIG_X86_TSC=y
CONFIG_X86_CMPXCHG64=y
CONFIG_X86_CMOV=y
CONFIG_X86_MINIMUM_CPU_FAMILY=64
CONFIG_X86_DEBUGCTLMSR=y
# CONFIG_PROCESSOR_SELECT is not set
CONFIG_CPU_SUP_INTEL=y
CONFIG_CPU_SUP_AMD=y
CONFIG_CPU_SUP_CENTAUR=y
# CONFIG_X86_DS is not set
CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y
CONFIG_DMI=y
CONFIG_SWIOTLB=y
CONFIG_IOMMU_HELPER=y
# CONFIG_IOMMU_API is not set
CONFIG_NR_CPUS=2
# CONFIG_SCHED_SMT is not set
CONFIG_SCHED_MC=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set
CONFIG_X86_LOCAL_APIC=y
CONFIG_X86_IO_APIC=y
# CONFIG_X86_REROUTE_FOR_BROKEN_BOOT_IRQS is not set
CONFIG_X86_MCE=y
CONFIG_X86_NEW_MCE=y
CONFIG_X86_MCE_INTEL=y
CONFIG_X86_MCE_AMD=y
CONFIG_X86_MCE_THRESHOLD=y
# CONFIG_X86_MCE_INJECT is not set
CONFIG_X86_THERMAL_VECTOR=y
# CONFIG_I8K is not set
# CONFIG_MICROCODE is not set
CONFIG_X86_MSR=y
CONFIG_X86_CPUID=y
CONFIG_X86_CPU_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_ARCH_PHYS_ADDR_T_64BIT=y
CONFIG_DIRECT_GBPAGES=y
# CONFIG_NUMA is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_SPARSEMEM_DEFAULT=y
CONFIG_ARCH_SPARSEMEM_ENABLE=y
CONFIG_ARCH_SELECT_MEMORY_MODEL=y
CONFIG_SELECT_MEMORY_MODEL=y
# CONFIG_FLATMEM_MANUAL is not set
# CONFIG_DISCONTIGMEM_MANUAL is not set
CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_MANUAL=y
CONFIG_SPARSEMEM=y
CONFIG_HAVE_MEMORY_PRESENT=y
CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_EXTREME=y
CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_VMEMMAP_ENABLE=y
CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_VMEMMAP=y

#
# Memory hotplug is currently incompatible with Software Suspend
#
CONFIG_PAGEFLAGS_EXTENDED=y
CONFIG_SPLIT_PTLOCK_CPUS=4
CONFIG_PHYS_ADDR_T_64BIT=y
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA_FLAG=1
CONFIG_BOUNCE=y
CONFIG_VIRT_TO_BUS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_MLOCK=y
CONFIG_HAVE_MLOCKED_PAGE_BIT=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_MMAP_MIN_ADDR=65536
CONFIG_X86_CHECK_BIOS_CORRUPTION=y
CONFIG_X86_BOOTPARAM_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_CHECK=y
CONFIG_X86_RESERVE_LOW_64K=y
CONFIG_MTRR=y
CONFIG_MTRR_SANITIZER=y
CONFIG_MTRR_SANITIZER_ENABLE_DEFAULT=0
CONFIG_MTRR_SANITIZER_SPARE_REG_NR_DEFAULT=1
CONFIG_X86_PAT=y
CONFIG_SECCOMP=y
# CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR is not set
CONFIG_HZ_100=y
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_300 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_1000 is not set
CONFIG_HZ=100
CONFIG_SCHED_HRTICK=y
# CONFIG_KEXEC is not set
# CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP is not set
CONFIG_PHYSICAL_START=0x1000000
# CONFIG_RELOCATABLE is not set
CONFIG_PHYSICAL_ALIGN=0x1000000
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU=y
CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO=y
# CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_ENABLE_MEMORY_HOTPLUG=y

#
# Power management and ACPI options
#
CONFIG_ARCH_HIBERNATION_HEADER=y
CONFIG_PM=y
CONFIG_PM_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_PM_VERBOSE=y
CONFIG_CAN_PM_TRACE=y
CONFIG_PM_TRACE=y
CONFIG_PM_TRACE_RTC=y
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP_SMP=y
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP=y
# CONFIG_SUSPEND is not set
CONFIG_HIBERNATION_NVS=y
CONFIG_HIBERNATION=y
CONFIG_PM_STD_PARTITION=""

#
# CPU Frequency scaling
#
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ is not set
CONFIG_CPU_IDLE=y
CONFIG_CPU_IDLE_GOV_LADDER=y

#
# Memory power savings
#
# CONFIG_I7300_IDLE is not set

#
# Bus options (PCI etc.)
#
# CONFIG_PCI is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_MSI is not set
CONFIG_ISA_DMA_API=y
# CONFIG_PCCARD is not set

#
# Executable file formats / Emulations
#
CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_COMPAT_BINFMT_ELF=y
# CONFIG_CORE_DUMP_DEFAULT_ELF_HEADERS is not set
# CONFIG_HAVE_AOUT is not set
CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC=y
CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION=y
# CONFIG_IA32_AOUT is not set
CONFIG_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_COMPAT_FOR_U64_ALIGNMENT=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_NET=y

#
# Networking options
#
CONFIG_PACKET=y
CONFIG_PACKET_MMAP=y
CONFIG_UNIX=y
CONFIG_XFRM=y
CONFIG_XFRM_USER=y
# CONFIG_XFRM_SUB_POLICY is not set
# CONFIG_XFRM_MIGRATE is not set
# CONFIG_XFRM_STATISTICS is not set
CONFIG_XFRM_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_NET_KEY=y
# CONFIG_NET_KEY_MIGRATE is not set
CONFIG_INET=y
# CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST is not set
# CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER is not set
CONFIG_IP_FIB_HASH=y
# CONFIG_IP_PNP is not set
# CONFIG_NET_IPIP is not set
# CONFIG_NET_IPGRE is not set
# CONFIG_ARPD is not set
# CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES is not set
CONFIG_INET_AH=y
CONFIG_INET_ESP=y
CONFIG_INET_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_BEET=y
CONFIG_INET_LRO=y
CONFIG_INET_DIAG=y
CONFIG_INET_TCP_DIAG=y
# CONFIG_TCP_CONG_ADVANCED is not set
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_CUBIC=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_TCP_CONG="cubic"
# CONFIG_TCP_MD5SIG is not set
CONFIG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_IPV6_PRIVACY=y
# CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTER_PREF is not set
# CONFIG_IPV6_OPTIMISTIC_DAD is not set
CONFIG_INET6_AH=y
CONFIG_INET6_ESP=y
CONFIG_INET6_IPCOMP=y
# CONFIG_IPV6_MIP6 is not set
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET6_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_BEET=y
# CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_ROUTEOPTIMIZATION is not set
CONFIG_IPV6_SIT=y
CONFIG_IPV6_NDISC_NODETYPE=y
CONFIG_IPV6_TUNNEL=y
# CONFIG_IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES is not set
# CONFIG_IPV6_MROUTE is not set
# CONFIG_NETWORK_SECMARK is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED=y

#
# Core Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_ACCT=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_GRE=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_UDPLITE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_AMANDA=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_H323=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IRC=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_NETBIOS_NS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PPTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SANE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SIP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_TPROXY is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CLASSIFY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNMARK=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_DSCP is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFLOG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFQUEUE=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NOTRACK is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_RATEEST=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TRACE is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPMSS=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPOPTSTRIP is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CLUSTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNBYTES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNLIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DSCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ESP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HASHLIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HELPER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPRANGE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_LENGTH=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MAC=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OWNER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_POLICY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_PKTTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_QUOTA=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RATEEST=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_REALM=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RECENT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RECENT_PROC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATISTIC=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STRING=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TCPMSS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TIME=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_U32=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OSF is not set
# CONFIG_IP_VS is not set

#
# IP: Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROC_COMPAT=y
# CONFIG_IP_NF_QUEUE is not set
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_AH=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ECN=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TTL=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REJECT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ULOG=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_NETMAP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_SNMP_BASIC=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_GRE=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_UDPLITE=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_IRC=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_AMANDA=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PPTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_H323=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_SIP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_CLUSTERIP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ECN=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TTL=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPFILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARP_MANGLE=y

#
# IPv6: Netfilter Configuration
#
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV6 is not set
# CONFIG_IP6_NF_QUEUE is not set
# CONFIG_IP6_NF_IPTABLES is not set
# CONFIG_IP_DCCP is not set
# CONFIG_IP_SCTP is not set
# CONFIG_TIPC is not set
# CONFIG_ATM is not set
# CONFIG_BRIDGE is not set
# CONFIG_NET_DSA is not set
# CONFIG_VLAN_8021Q is not set
# CONFIG_DECNET is not set
# CONFIG_LLC2 is not set
# CONFIG_IPX is not set
# CONFIG_ATALK is not set
# CONFIG_X25 is not set
# CONFIG_LAPB is not set
# CONFIG_ECONET is not set
# CONFIG_WAN_ROUTER is not set
# CONFIG_PHONET is not set
# CONFIG_IEEE802154 is not set
# CONFIG_NET_SCHED is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_ROUTE=y
# CONFIG_DCB is not set

#
# Network testing
#
# CONFIG_NET_PKTGEN is not set
# CONFIG_HAMRADIO is not set
# CONFIG_CAN is not set
# CONFIG_IRDA is not set
# CONFIG_BT is not set
CONFIG_AF_RXRPC=y
# CONFIG_AF_RXRPC_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_RXKAD is not set
# CONFIG_WIRELESS is not set
# CONFIG_WIMAX is not set
# CONFIG_RFKILL is not set
# CONFIG_NET_9P is not set

#
# Device Drivers
#

#
# Generic Driver Options
#
CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER_PATH="/sbin/hotplug"
CONFIG_STANDALONE=y
CONFIG_PREVENT_FIRMWARE_BUILD=y
CONFIG_FW_LOADER=y
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_IN_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE=""
CONFIG_SYS_HYPERVISOR=y
CONFIG_CONNECTOR=y
CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_MTD is not set
# CONFIG_PARPORT is not set
CONFIG_BLK_DEV=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_FD is not set
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_COW_COMMON is not set
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_CRYPTOLOOP=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_NBD is not set
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM is not set
# CONFIG_CDROM_PKTCDVD is not set
# CONFIG_ATA_OVER_ETH is not set
CONFIG_XEN_BLKDEV_FRONTEND=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_HD is not set
# CONFIG_MISC_DEVICES is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_IDE=y
# CONFIG_IDE is not set

#
# SCSI device support
#
# CONFIG_RAID_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_DMA is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_NETLINK is not set
# CONFIG_ATA is not set
# CONFIG_MD is not set
# CONFIG_MACINTOSH_DRIVERS is not set
CONFIG_NETDEVICES=y
CONFIG_DUMMY=y
# CONFIG_BONDING is not set
# CONFIG_MACVLAN is not set
# CONFIG_EQUALIZER is not set
# CONFIG_TUN is not set
# CONFIG_VETH is not set
# CONFIG_NET_ETHERNET is not set
# CONFIG_NETDEV_1000 is not set
# CONFIG_NETDEV_10000 is not set

#
# Wireless LAN
#
# CONFIG_WLAN_PRE80211 is not set
# CONFIG_WLAN_80211 is not set

#
# Enable WiMAX (Networking options) to see the WiMAX drivers
#
# CONFIG_WAN is not set
CONFIG_XEN_NETDEV_FRONTEND=y
# CONFIG_PPP is not set
# CONFIG_SLIP is not set
# CONFIG_NETCONSOLE is not set
# CONFIG_NETPOLL is not set
# CONFIG_NET_POLL_CONTROLLER is not set
# CONFIG_ISDN is not set
# CONFIG_PHONE is not set

#
# Input device support
#
CONFIG_INPUT=y
# CONFIG_INPUT_FF_MEMLESS is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_POLLDEV is not set

#
# Userland interfaces
#
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV=y
# CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_PSAUX is not set
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_SCREEN_X=1024
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_SCREEN_Y=768
# CONFIG_INPUT_JOYDEV is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_EVDEV is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_EVBUG is not set
CONFIG_XEN_KBDDEV_FRONTEND=y

#
# Input Device Drivers
#
CONFIG_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
CONFIG_KEYBOARD_ATKBD=y
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_LKKBD is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_NEWTON is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_STOWAWAY is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_SUNKBD is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_XTKBD is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSE is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_JOYSTICK is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_TABLET is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_MISC is not set

#
# Hardware I/O ports
#
CONFIG_SERIO=y
CONFIG_SERIO_I8042=y
# CONFIG_SERIO_SERPORT is not set
# CONFIG_SERIO_CT82C710 is not set
CONFIG_SERIO_LIBPS2=y
# CONFIG_SERIO_RAW is not set
# CONFIG_GAMEPORT is not set

#
# Character devices
#
CONFIG_VT=y
CONFIG_CONSOLE_TRANSLATIONS=y
CONFIG_VT_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_HW_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_VT_HW_CONSOLE_BINDING=y
CONFIG_DEVKMEM=y
# CONFIG_SERIAL_NONSTANDARD is not set

#
# Serial drivers
#
# CONFIG_SERIAL_8250 is not set
CONFIG_FIX_EARLYCON_MEM=y

#
# Non-8250 serial port support
#
CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS=y
# CONFIG_DEVPTS_MULTIPLE_INSTANCES is not set
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS=y
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTY_COUNT=64
CONFIG_HVC_DRIVER=y
CONFIG_HVC_IRQ=y
CONFIG_HVC_XEN=y
# CONFIG_IPMI_HANDLER is not set
# CONFIG_HW_RANDOM is not set
# CONFIG_NVRAM is not set
# CONFIG_RTC is not set
# CONFIG_GEN_RTC is not set
# CONFIG_R3964 is not set
# CONFIG_MWAVE is not set
# CONFIG_PC8736x_GPIO is not set
# CONFIG_RAW_DRIVER is not set
# CONFIG_HANGCHECK_TIMER is not set
# CONFIG_TCG_TPM is not set
# CONFIG_TELCLOCK is not set
# CONFIG_I2C is not set
# CONFIG_SPI is not set

#
# PPS support
#
# CONFIG_PPS is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_OPTIONAL_GPIOLIB=y
# CONFIG_GPIOLIB is not set
# CONFIG_W1 is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_SUPPLY is not set
# CONFIG_HWMON is not set
# CONFIG_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_THERMAL_HWMON is not set
# CONFIG_WATCHDOG is not set
CONFIG_SSB_POSSIBLE=y

#
# Sonics Silicon Backplane
#
CONFIG_SSB=y
# CONFIG_SSB_SILENT is not set
# CONFIG_SSB_DEBUG is not set

#
# Multifunction device drivers
#
# CONFIG_MFD_CORE is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_SM501 is not set
# CONFIG_HTC_PASIC3 is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_TMIO is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR is not set
# CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT is not set

#
# Graphics support
#
# CONFIG_VGASTATE is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_CONTROL is not set
CONFIG_FB=y
# CONFIG_FIRMWARE_EDID is not set
# CONFIG_FB_DDC is not set
# CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT is not set
# CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT is not set
# CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA is not set
# CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT is not set
# CONFIG_FB_CFB_REV_PIXELS_IN_BYTE is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FILLRECT=y
CONFIG_FB_SYS_COPYAREA=y
CONFIG_FB_SYS_IMAGEBLIT=y
# CONFIG_FB_FOREIGN_ENDIAN is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FOPS=y
CONFIG_FB_DEFERRED_IO=y
# CONFIG_FB_SVGALIB is not set
# CONFIG_FB_MACMODES is not set
# CONFIG_FB_BACKLIGHT is not set
# CONFIG_FB_MODE_HELPERS is not set
# CONFIG_FB_TILEBLITTING is not set

#
# Frame buffer hardware drivers
#
# CONFIG_FB_ARC is not set
# CONFIG_FB_VGA16 is not set
# CONFIG_FB_UVESA is not set
# CONFIG_FB_VESA is not set
# CONFIG_FB_N411 is not set
# CONFIG_FB_HGA is not set
# CONFIG_FB_S1D13XXX is not set
# CONFIG_FB_VIRTUAL is not set
CONFIG_XEN_FBDEV_FRONTEND=y
# CONFIG_FB_METRONOME is not set
# CONFIG_FB_MB862XX is not set
# CONFIG_FB_BROADSHEET is not set
# CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LCD_SUPPORT is not set

#
# Display device support
#
# CONFIG_DISPLAY_SUPPORT is not set

#
# Console display driver support
#
CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK is not set
CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DETECT_PRIMARY is not set
# CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_ROTATION is not set
# CONFIG_FONTS is not set
CONFIG_FONT_8x8=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
# CONFIG_LOGO is not set
# CONFIG_SOUND is not set
# CONFIG_HID_SUPPORT is not set
# CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT is not set
# CONFIG_MMC is not set
# CONFIG_MEMSTICK is not set
# CONFIG_NEW_LEDS is not set
# CONFIG_ACCESSIBILITY is not set
# CONFIG_EDAC is not set
# CONFIG_RTC_CLASS is not set
# CONFIG_DMADEVICES is not set
# CONFIG_AUXDISPLAY is not set
# CONFIG_UIO is not set

#
# TI VLYNQ
#
CONFIG_XEN_BALLOON=y
CONFIG_XEN_SCRUB_PAGES=y
CONFIG_XEN_DEV_EVTCHN=y
CONFIG_XENFS=y
CONFIG_XEN_COMPAT_XENFS=y
CONFIG_XEN_SYS_HYPERVISOR=y
# CONFIG_STAGING is not set
# CONFIG_X86_PLATFORM_DEVICES is not set

#
# Firmware Drivers
#
# CONFIG_EDD is not set
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_MEMMAP=y
# CONFIG_DELL_RBU is not set
# CONFIG_DCDBAS is not set
# CONFIG_DMIID is not set
# CONFIG_ISCSI_IBFT_FIND is not set

#
# File systems
#
CONFIG_EXT2_FS=y
CONFIG_EXT2_FS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_EXT2_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_EXT2_FS_SECURITY=y
CONFIG_EXT2_FS_XIP=y
CONFIG_EXT3_FS=y
# CONFIG_EXT3_DEFAULTS_TO_ORDERED is not set
CONFIG_EXT3_FS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_EXT3_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_EXT3_FS_SECURITY=y
# CONFIG_EXT4_FS is not set
CONFIG_FS_XIP=y
CONFIG_JBD=y
CONFIG_FS_MBCACHE=y
# CONFIG_REISERFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_JFS_FS is not set
CONFIG_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
# CONFIG_XFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_GFS2_FS is not set
# CONFIG_OCFS2_FS is not set
# CONFIG_BTRFS_FS is not set
CONFIG_FILE_LOCKING=y
CONFIG_FSNOTIFY=y
CONFIG_DNOTIFY=y
CONFIG_INOTIFY=y
CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y
# CONFIG_QUOTA is not set
# CONFIG_AUTOFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_AUTOFS4_FS is not set
# CONFIG_FUSE_FS is not set

#
# Caches
#
# CONFIG_FSCACHE is not set

#
# CD-ROM/DVD Filesystems
#
# CONFIG_ISO9660_FS is not set
# CONFIG_UDF_FS is not set

#
# DOS/FAT/NT Filesystems
#
# CONFIG_MSDOS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_VFAT_FS is not set
# CONFIG_NTFS_FS is not set

#
# Pseudo filesystems
#
CONFIG_PROC_FS=y
CONFIG_PROC_KCORE=y
CONFIG_PROC_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR=y
CONFIG_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_TMPFS=y
# CONFIG_TMPFS_POSIX_ACL is not set
# CONFIG_HUGETLBFS is not set
# CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE is not set
# CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_MISC_FILESYSTEMS is not set
CONFIG_NETWORK_FILESYSTEMS=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_V4 is not set
CONFIG_NFSD=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3=y
# CONFIG_NFSD_V3_ACL is not set
# CONFIG_NFSD_V4 is not set
CONFIG_LOCKD=y
CONFIG_LOCKD_V4=y
CONFIG_EXPORTFS=y
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
CONFIG_SUNRPC=y
# CONFIG_RPCSEC_GSS_KRB5 is not set
# CONFIG_RPCSEC_GSS_SPKM3 is not set
# CONFIG_SMB_FS is not set
CONFIG_CIFS=y
CONFIG_CIFS_STATS=y
# CONFIG_CIFS_STATS2 is not set
# CONFIG_CIFS_WEAK_PW_HASH is not set
# CONFIG_CIFS_UPCALL is not set
# CONFIG_CIFS_XATTR is not set
# CONFIG_CIFS_DEBUG2 is not set
# CONFIG_CIFS_DFS_UPCALL is not set
# CONFIG_CIFS_EXPERIMENTAL is not set
# CONFIG_NCP_FS is not set
# CONFIG_
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what distro you are using. I wonder why you don't use a distro like OpenSUSE that comes with XEN built-in and configured?

I would say that is where you are going wrong. Installing source and patching is fine if you are a developer, but for building servers to do real work, it is better to stick with a dsitro that supports XEN.

Or, if you have the flexibility to choose something other than Linux, OpenSolaris also has XEN included in the most recent distros.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. I'm using Debian as my dom0 distro. I'd rather not change distros if I can help it, so if I can get this to work it would be good. I also wonder whether it's the domU kernel at fault, e.g. perhaps I need to switch on another config item when I build the domU kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with live migration:

Dom0: Xenserver 5.5, Kernel 2.6.18

DomU: Gentoo, Kernel 2.6.31-r7 ([code.google.com/p/gentoo-xen-kernel/](http://code.google.com/p/gentoo-xen-kernel/downloads/list))

DomU dmesg output:

```
PM: Device rtc_cmos failed to suspend late: error -22
dpm_suspend_noirq() failed: -22
Xen suspend failed (-22)
```

/holger

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into a similar issue with Xen 3.1 and Xen 3.0.3 with a DomU running 2.6.31.6 (vanilla from kernel.org).  On Xen 3.3, the issue doesn't appear, so I'm surprised to see it returning with Xen 3.4.1.

I'm trying to debug this one to see which kernel call is failing.

UPDATE 12/10/2009: I contacted Jeremy Fitzhardinge about the issue as he's one of the folks writing a lot of patches for the current kernel tree related to pv_ops.  He said:

> There are a number of bugs with save/restore in vanilla Linux at the moment.  I've submitted fixes for them, but I don't think they've been picked up yet.  In the mean time, I recommend using the xen.git kernel.

He's referring to his git repository here: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/jeremy/xen.git

I built a kernel from his latest commits (it's 2.6.31.6 right now) and I'm able to use `xm save` without a problem.  However, when I try to use `xm restore`, there's a big networking problem.  Running anything networking related (like `ifconfig`) causes the entire domU to lock up.

Be sure to check out this thread from the xen-devel mailing list as well: http://lists.xensource.com/archives/html/xen-devel/2009-11/msg00334.html. It contains a lot of good information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling ACPI in the domU?